# Swift - Closure cannot have keyword arguments Error In Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, swift, api

I have updated to Xcode 7.3 and some of my Libraries including **Toast** and **CNPopupButton** are giving me this error:
*Closure cannot have keyword arguments*

And then it asks me to delete the argument Type Name.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: what is the type/signature of selectionHandler property ?

Comment: It is correctly declared as follows:

typedef void(^SelectionHandler) (CNPPopupButton *button);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Swift 2.2 (which comes with Xcode 7.3) a declaration like:

```
button.selectionHandler = { (CNPPopupButton button) -> Void in
```

should be

```
button.selectionHandler = { (button : CNPPopupButton) -> Void in
```

Which indeed feels more Swift-ish. If you don't want to pin down the type, you can also use the short-hand syntax:

```
button.selectionHandler = { button in
```